# Return County name from address using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geocoding

I'm using PostGIS to geocode address data like this:

```
SELECT pprint_addy(addy), ST_AsText(geomout) FROM geocode('Chicago, IL');
```

I've loaded all the TIGER data for each US state from the US census following [this tutorial.](https://experimentalcraft.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/how-to-make-a-postgis-tiger-geocoder-in-less-than-5-days/)

Everything works as expected and I can retrieve co-ordinates from parial text addresses.

What I'm wondering is: Is there a way to use a partial address to return a county instead of co-ordinates?

Ideally, I'd submit `Chicago, IL` as my input and return `Cook`

As you can tell, I'm a beginner.  Is there a tutorial that covers this?

**Version Information:**

```
PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit
```

Comment: Did you find a way to get the county back? I'm looking to do the same thing